# Visual C: Namespace Scope Bug or Obscure Feature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, c++17

You will need three different files: `header.h`, `source.cpp` & `main.cpp`.

```
// header.h
#pragma once

namespace A
{

  namespace B
  {
    class C 
    {
    public: static void f();
    };

    void g();
  }

  using namespace B;
}
```

```
// source.cpp
#include "Header.h"

namespace A
{
  void C::f()
  {
    #pragma message( "Compiling " __FUNCTION__ )
  }

  void g()
  {
    #pragma message( "Compiling " __FUNCTION__ )
  }
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
  A::C::f();
  A::g();
}
```

I expected no error, instead it looks like the class and function **belong to different namespaces, although declared & implemented in the same scope**:

```
1 > Source.cpp
1 > Compiling A::B::C::f
1 > Compiling A::g
1 > Generating Code...
1 > ConsoleApplication10.obj : error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl A::B::g(void)" ( ? g@B@A@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

The code is generated by a tool.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
  void C::f()
  {
    #pragma message( "Compiling " __FUNCTION__ )
  }
```

The `f` here is a qualified name (qualified by `C`). As such, C++ has to figure out what `C` you're talking about. To do that, it has to look at the available unqualified names and find the identifier `C` within them. Because you're in namespace `A`, and namespace `A` has had all of namespace `B` dumped into it, `C` will resolve to `A::B::C`. And thus, `C::f` becomes `A::B::C::f`.

By contrast, when you do this:

```
  void g()
  {
    #pragma message( "Compiling " __FUNCTION__ )
  }
```

`g` is an *unqualified name*. As such, that name means exactly what it says: the name `g` within the current namespace. Which is `A`.

`using` declarations do not change the current namespace; it only changes the name lookup rules for names. Because `g` is an unqualified name, there's nothing to look up; you meant `A::g`.

Which means you are *not* defining the function `A::B::g`.

So what you have is a header that says "I promise that someone, somewhere will define `A::B::g`," but nobody actually does. `source.cpp` only defined `A::g`, which `main.cpp` is not attempting to call (because it has no idea that it exists).

Hence the linker error.

Comment: I was just thinking about adding the stuff about `A::B::C::f()` to my answer, but couldn't quite work out how! You've done it beautifully - have my upvote, Sir!

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that `main.cpp` can see nothing of `source.cpp`, so it doesn't know about the actual `void A::g()` function declared/defined therein!

What `main.cpp` ***does*** see is a *namespace* `A` which is `using namespace B`. So, when `main.cpp` calls `A::g()`, the compiler can only assume you refer to `void A::B::g()` - and thus marks this as a function to link in.

But, as correctly diagnosed by the linker, you have not provided a ***definition*** for this function - so it is unresolved.